How to simplify learning curve for FO and IDP-Z3 for practical usage?
I'm new for IDP-Z3, but I have 20+ years of experience in development.
I have found very good getting started guide (and have got the idea), the reference guide and source codes (which are also very important).
Now I would like to use IDP-Z3.
How to simplify learning curve for FO and IDP-Z3 for practical usage?
Also I would like to understand is it possible to use FO as a language for data modeling for API?
Are there any books, extended manuals or online cources for FO and IDP-Z3?
For example, I have found that IDP-Z3 can help in the following generic forms of reasoning: Model checking, Model expansion, Possible values, Propagation, Explanation, Optimization, Relevance.
But for now it's difficult for me to understand how to do it.

I believe you are referring to these materials, but I will drop the link here just in case. Unfortunately, there are no books particularly related to the IDP system. Additional examples, which can be useful for learning, are available as a part of the older system IDP3. Here is the link to the online IDE; in the navigation menu there is a tab "file" and there are different categories. Here you can also see examples using different inference methods. Note that the syntax in the new system IDP-Z3 is slightly different.
Perhaps one way to improve the learning curve is to get familiar with model theory.
Data modeling for API should be possible. The main problem (in general) with IDP-Z3 is integration in bigger systems. E.g., the output of the IDP-Z3 containing information about an API would require additional parsing to actually extract the data. Luckily, there is an ongoing development regarding this issue.
I am not aware of any online courses. There are two master's courses at the KU Leuven that use using IDP system: Knowledge Representation and Modeling of Complex Systems.
